# Python Pip install LDTP fails

Tags: 15.04, python, pip

I'm on Ubuntu Vivid (15.04) and I have installed Python 2.7 (default) and Python 3.4.

Now, why does `pip install ldtp` fails to install (fails to create temporary directory `/tmp/pip-build-6j6vgvsb/ldtp`)?

However, I ran pip install libxml2dom ==> successfully installed package! (just to test **pip install works** for other packages)

---

I have tried to manually perform the steps pip performs, but I'm not sure if I arrived at the real problem:

- I downloaded [LDTP](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/l/ldtp/ldtp-1.0.0.tar.gz#md5=b3fc52b1ab2c48b825bcc463003d95f9) using wget
- I unpackaged it (*tar -xvfz
  LDTP.tar.gz*)
- Ran ./configure and installed the missing libraries
  (*aptitude install libxml2-dev libglib2.0-dev python-gobject-dev*)
- ./configure still complains about the missing **cspi-1.0** package
- I ran pip install LDTP again - no change
- however, I ran pip install libxml2dom ==> successfully installed package! (just to test pip install works for other packages)
- Now, CSPI is supposed to be part of an AT-SPI package so I installed *gir1.2-atspi-2.0, libatspi2.0-0, libatspi2.0-dev, python-pyatspi, python-pyatspi2, python3-pyatspi, python3-pyatspi2*

So pip install fails because:

- it does not deal with dependencies (libraries *XML2, Glib2, GObject, **CSPI***)
- under the hood, pip calls ./configure and that fails to build and exits without any warning
- LDTP ./configure still needs CSPI 1.0 package, all I have installed is *AT-SPI 2.0*

---

Log extract:

```
~/ldtp-1.0.0# ./configure  
checking for CSPI_1_0... configure: error: Package requirements (cspi-1.0 >= 1.2.0) were not met:

No package 'cspi-1.0' found
```

Please check the [detailed log](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ZuNNpbaC)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how I missed this:

```
$ sudo aptitude install ldtp python-ldtp
```

Works like a charm! At least now I understand better how pip install works!